# Difference between the distribution of a sample and the sampling distribution

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics

Describe in your own words (do not directly quote any source) the difference between the distribution of a sample and the sampling distribution.  Use an example in which the original population has a binomial distribution.  You will probably use concepts from the book or another source, so be sure to cite any concepts that come from such sources (even if you paraphrase)

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Sampling distribution* of a sample statistic is the probabilistic distribution of the statistic of interest for a random sample. In comparison, the *distribution of a sample* is the probabilistic distribution of the observations in the sample.

The former is roughly telling you how likely it is to get some specific sample when you draw a large amount of samples. The latter tells you how likely it is to get a specific observation in a single random sample.